# A JFrame with custom icon in Java 11

Tags: java

I'm trying to get a JFrame with a custom icon, but nothing works. Here's what I have right now, in Java 11:

```java
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class GUI1 extends JFrame {
    public static void main (String args[]) {
        GUI1 gui = new GUI1();
        gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        gui.setSize(700, 500);
        gui.setVisible(true);
        gui.setTitle("GUI");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An Example.

```
public class GUI extends JFrame{
    // The icon file is in the same directory as this file.
    protected static final ImageIcon ICON = new ImageIcon("Icon.png");

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new GUI();
    }

    public GUI(){
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(640, 480));
        setTitle("GUI");
        setIconImage(ICON.getImage());
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```